# Dynamic UiOutput Causing Issue when Adding Inputs to a DataFrame Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, purrr

I have an application where the user selects the stocks she want's to analyze. Depending on the number of stocks chosen, the app will render equal amounts of UIOuputs where the user can choose the weight for each stock. So for example, if you choose 6 stocks to analyze, 6 uioutputs will render each asking to select a weight.

The problem I am having is, I would like to create a data frame with the inputs. So if a user selects AAPl and MSFT with weights .50 and .50. I would like to create a df:

```
Ticker  Weight
AAPL    .50
MSFT    .50
```

However, when I try and create the dataframe I get an error inputs are not of the same length. I believe this is because of how shiny reactivity works (not ordered). Any inputs would be greatly appreciated. Below is the app.

```
library(shiny)
library(purrr)
library(tidyverse)
library(DT)
tickers = c("SPY", "IWM", "QQQ", "TLT", "AGG", "GLD", "SLV")

ui <- fluidPage(

    # Application title
    titlePanel("Portfolio Builder"),

    #select the stocks you want to analyze
    mainPanel(
       selectizeInput("mult", "chose stock", choices = tickers, selected = "SPY", multiple = T),
       uiOutput("plo"),
       dataTableOutput("dataTab")
    )


)

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(input, output) {

 output$plo = renderUI({
     z = length(input$mult)
     name = input$mult
     map2(seq(z), name,  ~ numericInput(inputId = paste0("hey",.x), label = paste("weight", .y), value = 10))

     })

 weights = reactiveValues()

 observe({weights$current = map(seq(length(input$mult)),~input[[paste0("hey",.x)]]) %>% unlist()})

 mat = reactive({
   #if(length(weights$current) == length(input$mult)){
   df = data.frame(ticker = input$mult, weight = weights$current) %>% mutate(weightPct = weights$current/sum(weights$current))
  # }else{NULL}
 })

 output$dataTab = renderDataTable({
   mat()
 })


observe(print(weights$current))
observe(print(input$mult))



}
```

Comment: I added: `output$my_df <- renderDataTable({mat()})` to the server and `dataTableOutput("my_df")` to the UI. It appeared to create the data frame properly . What am I missing?

Comment: Hi Ryan I have updated the code to add in your datatable + a transformation. You should see the error now when you add a new stock. I added in a solution in # if(length...). However I think this solution is not the proper "shiny way"

Comment: You can add `req()` a needed. I'm confused by your observe call. If everything is in a reactive context, you shouldn't have to use the observer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I converted your `observe()` and `reactiveValues()` to a single `reactive()` object. This way it reacts to changes without the complexity you had. The other big difference is that I converted the `weights` object to a list, but I think it should still be easy to follow. The data frame error persisted as the length of the user inputs and weights momentarily mismatch, so I returned the length check you already had:

```
library(shiny)
library(purrr)
library(tidyverse)
library(DT)
tickers = c("SPY", "IWM", "QQQ", "TLT", "AGG", "GLD", "SLV")
suppressWarnings()

ui <- fluidPage(

  # Application title
  titlePanel("Portfolio Builder"),

  #select the stocks you want to analyze
  mainPanel(
    selectizeInput("mult", "chose stock", choices = tickers, selected = "SPY", multiple = T),
    uiOutput("plo"),
    dataTableOutput("dataTab")
  )


)

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(input, output) {

  output$plo = renderUI({
    z = length(input$mult)
    name = input$mult
    map2(seq(z), name,  ~ numericInput(inputId = paste0("hey",.x), label = paste("weight", .y), value = 10))

  })

  weights = reactive({
    req(input$mult)
    list(current = map(seq(length(input$mult)),~input[[paste0("hey",.x)]]) %>% unlist())
  })


  mat = reactive({
    req(weights()$current)
    if(length(weights()$current) == length(input$mult)){
      df = data.frame(ticker = input$mult, weight = weights()$current) %>% mutate(weightPct = weights()$current/sum(weights()$current))
    }
  })

  output$dataTab = renderDataTable({
    req(mat())
    mat()
  })


}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```